# How to assign random names to users based on already present user ids

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column with more than 100,000 unique user ids and these user ids are repeated throughout .I want to assign all unique user ids with a random name and this name should be repeated in their second occurrence as well in the user ids column .

I have tried randbetween but this would give multiple names to similar user ids as well .

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,5), "George", "Matt", "Ann", "Sam", "Jennifer")
```

the output should be like:

```
user_id name
2       sam
2       sam
3       kate
4       lillian
3       kate
```

Comment: I don't understand what's on your sheet currently.  You *have* a column with 100k ids, but how to the numbers and names you ultimately want relate to that column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do a VLOOKUP on the data first,  If that errors then assign a random name:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$A$1:B1,2,FALSE),CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,5), "George", "Matt", "Ann", "Sam", "Jennifer"))
```

[image]

---

This will ensure that the names are only used once, but it requires that there be a name for every unique user_id:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$A$1:B1,2,FALSE),INDEX({"George","Matt","Ann","Sam","Jennifer"},AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($1:$5)/(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,{"George";"Matt";"Ann";"Sam";"Jennifer"})=0),RANDBETWEEN(1,5-SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,{"George","Matt","Ann","Sam","Jennifer"})>0))))))
```

[image]

Comment: THIS KEEPS ON UPDATING IF I AM CHOOSING ANY OTHER CELL

Comment: How to keep the names once created without refreshing them?

Comment: You will need to copy and past the values back on themselves.  `RANDBETWEEN` is volatile and will update each time Excel re-Calculates.

Comment: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,$B$1:D1,2,FALSE),RAND()*(9999999999-1000000000)+1000000000)      If I want to generate random phone numbers and do the same like name what will i have to change in this .Please help!!

Comment: `RAND` is also volatile and will change every time Excel Re-Calculates.

Comment: That is a new question and should get its own post.